# control-b: is it reserved?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was surprised when a function that I wrote in python/tkinter and binded to Ctrl-b behaved strangely (specific: it was losing the value of the selected text, so that text.index(SEL_FIRST) was undefined).

I was surprised when, after changing the more improbable things I binded it instead to something else - and it worked!

I searched but didnt find anything: is Control-b binded to something default in tkinter???

alessandro

Comment: code,code,code --show us the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the text widget, from the [official tk text widget documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M162):

> "The Left and Right keys move the
>   insertion cursor one character to the
>   left or right; they also clear any
>   selection in the text...Control-b and
>   Control-f behave the same as Left and
>   Right, respectively."

Comment: Yes, talking about the text widget. I didnt find it in the doc since I was using the Tkinter docs at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/text.html, and there it was not mentioned.    So...??? Control-b cannot be remapped in some way?

Comment: @alessandro: yes, it can be remapped. All bindings in Tk can be modified, deleted, replaced or augmented. It's one of Tk's great strengths.  The binding is on the text widget class "Text" which you can access with the method `bind_class`. I can't give a complete explanation in a small comment, so do a little research on tk bindtags and class bindings. Also read up on what `return break` does in a widget binding (generally speaking, it prevents a class binding to the same event from firing)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bryan, here's the link - obviously on effbot http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm:

(...)

> You could use the bind_class method to
>   modify the bindings on the class
>   level, but that would change the
>   behavior of all text widgets in the
>   application. An easier solution is to
>   prevent Tkinter from propagating the
>   event to other handlers; just return
>   the string “break” from your event
>   handler:

```
def ignore(event):
    return "break"
text.bind("<Return>", ignore)
```

> or

```
text.bind("<Return>", lambda e: "break")
```

> By the way, if you really want to
>   change the behavior of all text
>   widgets in your application, here’s
>   how to use the bind_class method:

```
top.bind_class("Text", "<Return>", lambda e: None)
```

> But there are a lot of reasons why you
>   shouldn’t do this. For example, it
>   messes things up completely the day
>   you wish to extend your application
>   with some cool little UI component you
>   downloaded from the net. Better use
>   your own Text widget specialization,
>   and keep Tkinter’s default bindings
>   intact:

```
class MyText(Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        apply(Text.__init__, (self, master), kw)
        self.bind("<Return>", lambda e: "break")
```